# How to remove plugin google+?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I tried to remove the `cordova-plugin-googleplus` plug-in from `iOS` with the following command:

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-googleplus
```

I then got this error:

> Error: Cannot read property 'buffer' of undefined.

Any help please.

Comment: Improved the formulation and formatting. This question still needs to clarify when the error occurred. Was it as a response to the issued command, or during another action?

Comment: It's probably a bug on cordova CLI. Which version are you using? and the node version?

Answer (score -1):

Try running your cmd as admin and then write

`cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-googleplus`

I once faced the same error and running the cmd as administrator solved it. Unless you added the plugin with a github URL then you should write `cordova plugin rm https:\\the_link_to_the_plugin`

Comment: he says it's ios, so I don't think he is using windows, so no CMD. And no, even if you install from github, you remove the plugin using the id, not the git url